# Python find min and max in realtime stream without full array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I have a continuous stream of values coming in, many millions of records.
I need to find the minimum and maximum in that has arrived so far in real-time as numbers keep coming in. The whole data array is not available. Data arrived is not stored. Min max range is also unknown.

I tried something like this, but it isn't working perfectly. Is there a better way to solve these using libraries, `numpy`, `scipy`?

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()

test = rng.choice(np.arange(-100,100, dtype=int), 10, replace=False)
testmax = 0
testmin = 0
for i in test: #simulates a stream
    if i < testmax:
        testmin = i
    if i > testmax:
        testmax = i
    if i < testmin:
        testmin = i


print (test, 'min: ',testmin, 'max: ', testmax)


>>> print (test, 'min: ',testmin, 'max: ', testmax)
[ 39 -32  61 -18 -53 -57 -69  98 -88 -47] min:  -47 max:  98 #should be -88 and 98
>>>
>>> print (test, 'min: ',testmin, 'max: ', testmax)
[-65 -53   1   2  26 -62  82  70  39 -44] min:  -44 max:  82 #should be -65 and 82
>>>
```

Comment: The line `if i < testmax: testmin = i` is a typo

Comment: You need to initialize `testmax` to a value lower than any possible values, and `testmin` to a value higher than any possible values. In the loop you only need 2 tests, not 3: one for `i > testmax`, the other for `i < testmin`.

Comment: @Barmar I do have any idea of the range for approximate initiation. I have to assume nothing.

Comment: Do you actually have NumPy values or not? What is the actual "stream"?

Comment: You say you *"need to find the minimum and maximum in that has arrived so far in real-time as numbers keep coming in"*, but your code only shows the *final* min/max. Which is it?

Comment: @KellyBundy  I do not have a numpy array. The numbers come in from continuous measurements. I used `-100 100` to generate numbers to keep it simple, they are similar to getting measurments.

Comment: Also, what does *"isn't working perfectly"* mean? What's the issue with it?

Comment: @KellyBundy It is a system where continuous measurements are done, with each measurement I get a number. I do not have any reference or estimate range where I use the first measurment as a reference to initiate. Each number needs to be compared with the previous derived min or max. If I assume zero, the code gets max value correct and fails on min.

Comment: What about my earlier question, do you need the intermediate min/max values or only the final one?

Comment: @KellyBundy Only the final ones.

Comment: What type are the values? NumPy ints? Python ints? Something else?

Comment: @These are astronomical measurement values in double for precision in a c++ code. Python is for wrapping for analytics.

Comment: So NumPy float64, or Python float?

Comment: @KellyBundy Numpy float64, since Numpy is made with c/c++.

Comment: @KellyBundy The OP asked me a question, I responded before reading the answers. I've deleted it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake (typo) was pointed out in the comments, but you only need two comparisons--this can be done using the ternary operator. You should also initialize the max to be negative infinity and the min to be positive infinity. This helps avoid cases where, for example, you set min to 0 but the smallest number actually seen in the stream is greater than 0.

```py
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

stream_min = -100
stream_max = 100
test = rng.choice(np.arange(stream_min, stream_max+1, dtype=int),
                  10,
                  replace=False)

testmax = -float("inf")
testmin = float("inf")

# simulates a stream
for i in test:
    testmax = i if i > testmax else testmax
    testmin = i if i < testmin else testmin


print (test, "min: ", testmin, "max: ", testmax)
# [ 97  49 -83  26 -15 -16  38 -82 -60  69] min:  -83 max:  97
```

Why the ternary operator over using `min`/`max`? Well, it's faster.

```py
stream_min = -1000
stream_max = 1000
test = rng.choice(np.arange(stream_min, stream_max+1, dtype=int),
                  500,
                  replace=False)

def ternary():
    testmax = -float("inf")
    testmin = float("inf")

    for i in test:
        testmax = i if i > testmax else testmax
        testmin = i if i < testmin else testmin

    return testmin, testmax

def plainif():
    testmax = -float("inf")
    testmin = float("inf")

    for i in test:
        if i > testmax:
            testmax = i
        if i < testmin:
            testmin = i

    return testmin, testmax

def minmax():
    testmax = -float("inf")
    testmin = float("inf")

    for i in test:
        testmax = max(i, testmax)
        testmin = min(i, testmax)

    return testmin, testmax

%timeit ternary() 
55.4 µs ± 3.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
%timeit plainif()
50.6 µs ± 2.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
%timeit minmax()
170 µs ± 6.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Using an `if` statement vs the ternary operator is nearly equivalent (the `if` is a hair faster).

Comment: I used `-100` `100` to generate numbers. But in real I do have any idea of the range to compare against.

Comment: You can use negative and positive infinity instead. See my updated answer.

Comment: Since they said "many millions", I'd use at least maybe a million. And then something like reading chunks of 1000 and calling min() and max() on them might be faster.

Comment: @jared use of negative and positive infinity seems to work in tests I just did.

Comment: @KellyBundy I was thinking that grouping might be an option. Maybe add that to your answer?

Comment: Done, though irritatingly it seems to still be slower, at least in Python 3.11. I thought min/max were only slow when called with very little work, like min(a,b). Thought they're fast when called on large enough iterables. Oh well. I think the Python people recently made them faster, though I don't remember the details and in which Python version...

Comment: [Another](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3jyoAQWaJgi2QSC3SKEktLtHkAomBWLmJFUAJMCszD8jKS60o0cgEKgCrSMsvUshUAEpklliBBcBGpQHF7GC6EeKoRmbCxVNzwDpsYLZg0QG2OhNiZ1FqSWlRHkxcB2YkxDNQP8H8BgA) (not tested) that might be faster if the stream is increasing so that `i > testmax` is often true and he second test is avoided (because `elif`).

Comment: @KellyBundy You're right, no reason to do both `if` checks. I just ran the `timeit` and it does shave off a little bit of time. I will add that to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Note I also changed the initialization, and that's necessary in order to use `elif` like that. If the stream is strictly increasing, then your updated `plainif` always updates testmax, never updates testmin, and thus ends up with an invalid testmin.

Comment: (Well, alternatively, that could be fixed with for example `return min(testmin, testmax), testmax`. But I prefer to do it with the different initialization. Partly because that also has the advantage of working not just for numbers but also for other things like strings etc.)

Comment: @KellyBundy True. I think I will revert my edit because using your initialization might be an issue with the actual case since you would probably already have entered the loop once the stream started.

Answer (score 2):

Note that Python conveniently provides `math.inf` and `-math.inf` which are floating point numbers guaranteed to be larger and smaller than any possible integers. So just write:

```
testmax = -math.inf
testmin = math.inf
for value in ...:
    testmax = max(testmax, value)
    testmin = min(testmin, value)
```

Comment: I preferred the ternary operator in my answer because it's faster than using `min`/`max`.

Comment: @jared If you want fast, then why don't you just use an if statement?

Comment: @KellyBundy If vs ternary are nearly the same with the if being slightly faster (though I find the ternary to be cleaner). But using `min`/`max` is more than 2x slower (on my machine). I've updated my answer to include the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

A fun itertools version in case someone *actually* wants the realtime min/max, not just the final ones:

```py
from itertools import tee, accumulate

test = 1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6

for testmin, testmax in zip(*map(accumulate, tee(test), (min, max))):
    print(testmin, testmax)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY5LCsIwFEXnWcUdJvI68IsILiaUBAPNh_QVqltx0oG6J3djYhXBN7kP7odzfaQzn2KYpvvAttk_bzZHD8cmc4xdD-dTzAw2hqDbdvBDp9kIwaZnHLEkNCvCusiGsC2yE8LGjOp7F2h-9AgXcHFJLrxO8jdUfSNrRhHku1DCSqmDQLmUXWD5v6Vm1g_yF_0F)):

```
1 1
-2 1
-2 3
-4 3
-4 5
-6 5
```

---

Another solution, reading chunks of 1000:

```py
from random import random
from itertools import islice

test = [random() for _ in range(10**6)]

testmin = float('inf')
testmax = float('-inf')
it = iter(test)
while chunk := list(islice(it, 1000)):
    testmin = min(testmin, min(chunk))
    testmax = max(testmax, max(chunk))

print(testmin, testmax)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RVBBCsIwEMRrXrE3s9JCvYgIfYmIFE3sYpqUdEV9ixcv-ihfY5qkNIcNMzu7s8zr2z-5dfb9_txYl9vfotTedeAbew4fdb3znJGIHWLl2TkzTE0aDJ2UEKwGhhr2SSwRtPNwBLLj-EXJdbVabfCQhF2ga9DGNSyXZPUSE908ZrpMPI1bR1c5KlDcWzIKTu3NXmFXg6GBZbpBEhewrqoKcScgvNkpVJlREUGcR5xl0TlUmVERwSQTvSfL84oswpRaDm8K8Q8)

Comment: I thought about the chunk version some more. In an actual scenario, one would have to collect the stream to build the list/iterable, then perform the min/max on the collected values, and repeat the collection. The process of collecting and operating may end up being too slow that one could miss incoming data. Does that make sense?

Comment: @jared Good point. Depends on how their "stream" works. Might be a problem, or might not.